# Lottie animation as loading indicator- Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a xamarin forms app which contains a pie graph using **microcharts**. The data for the graph is obtained from Web API. Everything works fine.Every time graph loads data from web API, there is some delay.So the appearance of graph will also takes time. What I am trying to do is use **Lottie animation** as the loading indicator before the graph appears.The animation shows but it gets flickered and load the graph.

**What I have done**

**My xaml**

```
  <Grid>
         <forms1:AnimationView 
                x:Name="AnimationView"                
                Animation="graphloading.json"       
                AutoPlay="True"
                Margin="10"              
                BackgroundColor="Transparent"                           
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />    

                        <forms:ChartView x:Name="Chart1" isVisible="False"
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>                     
                    </Grid>
```

**My Xaml.cs file**

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {              
        await LoadDynamicGraph();
    }

    private async Task LoadDynamicGraph()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {                                          
                    // Graph Loading API call code                          
                        if (GraphDataObj[0] != null)
                        {
                            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                            {

                                AnimationView.IsPlaying = false;
                                AnimationView.IsVisible = false;
                                Chart1.IsVisible = true;                                
                                foreach (var item in GraphDataObj[0].DailyScore)
                                {
                                    FirstGraphData = new List<ChartEntry>
                                    {
                                      new ChartEntry(float.Parse(item.CompletedItems))
                                    {

                                        Label = "Completed",                                           
                                       // ValueLabel = item.CompletedItems,
                                        Color = SKColor.Parse("#c90484"),
                                        TextColor = SKColor.Parse("#FFFFFF"),
                                    },

                                      new ChartEntry(float.Parse(item.TotalOpenItems))
                                    {
                                        Label = "Total ",
                                       // ValueLabel = item.TotalOpenItems,
                                        Color = SKColor.Parse("#00a8f3"),
                                        TextColor = SKColor.Parse("#FFFFFF"),
                                    }
                                    };
                                }
                                Chart1.Chart = new PieChart()
                                {
                                    Entries = FirstGraphData,
                                    BackgroundColor = SKColor.Parse("#002F4F4F")
                                };

                            });
                        }

        });

    }
```

Currently the animation simply just appears and go. I want to make it show some time and then load the graph. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set this

```
AnimationView.IsPlaying = false;
AnimationView.IsVisible = false;
Chart1.IsVisible = true;
```

on the end of your function. It will still be pretty fast. U can try to set timer once.

```
      finish = true;
      Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), () =>
            {
                If(finish){
                    finish = false;
                    return true;}
                //there turn off your animation
                return false;
            });
```